# Best and most efficient way to count tokens words

Tags: r

I have a CSV that starts with 3 columns. A cumulative percentage column of Costs, a Cost column, and a keyword column. The R script works for small files but totally dies (never finishes) when I feed it the actual file (which has a million rows). Can you help me make this script more efficient? The Token.Count is the one I'am having trouble creating. Thank you!

```
# Token Histogram

# Import CSV data from Report Downloader API Feed
Mydf <- read.csv("Output_test.csv.csv", sep=",", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# Helps limit the dataframe according the HTT
# Change number to:
# .99 for big picture
# .8 for HEAD
limitor <- Mydf$CumuCost <= .8
# De-comment to ONLY measure TORSO
#limitor <- (Mydf$CumuCost <= .95 & Mydf$CumuCost > .8)
# De-comment to ONLY measure TAIL
#limitor <- (Mydf$CumuCost <= 1 & Mydf$CumuCost > .95)
# De-comment to ONLY measure Non-HEAD
#limitor <- (Mydf$CumuCost <= 1 & Mydf$CumuCost > .8)

# Creates a column with HTT segmentation labels
# Creates a dataframe
HTT <- data.frame()
# Populates dataframe according to conditions
HTT <- ifelse(Mydf$CumuCost <= .8,"HEAD",ifelse(Mydf$CumuCost <= .95,"TORSO","TAIL"))
# Add the column to Mydf and rename it HTT
Mydf <- transform(Mydf, HTT = HTT)

# Count all KWs in account by using the dimension function
KWportfolioSize <- dim(Mydf)[1]

# Percent of portfolio
PercentofPortfolio <- sum(limitor)/KWportfolioSize

# Length of Keyword -- TOO SLOW
# Uses the Tau package
# My function takes the row number and returns the number of tokens
library(tau)
Myfun = function(n) {
  sum(sapply(Mydf$Keyword.text[n], textcnt, split = "[[:space:][:punct:]]+", method = "string", n = 1L))}
# Creates a dataframe to hold the results
Token.Count <- data.frame()
# Loops until last row and store it in data.frame
for (i in c(1:dim(Mydf)[1])) {Token.Count <- rbind(Token.Count,Myfun(i))}
# Add the column to Mydf
Mydf <- transform(Mydf, Token.Count = Token.Count)
# Not quite sure why but the column needs renaming in this case
colnames(Mydf)[dim(Mydf)[2]] <- "Token.Count"
```

Comment: can you link to a piece of sample data? Feel free to make it synthetic, just representative enough so folks can test their method against yours to be sure they are faster.

Comment: CumuCost Cost Keyword.text
0.004394288 678.5 north+face+outlet
0.006698245 80.05 kinect sensor
0.008738991 79.51 x box 360 250

Comment: 'data.frame':   74231 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ CumuCost    : num  0.00439 0.0067 0.00874 0.01067 0.01258 ...
 $ Cost        : num  1678 880 780 736 731 ...
 $ Keyword.text: chr  "north+face+outlet" "kinect sensor" "x box 360 250" ...
 $ HTT         : Factor w/ 1 level "HEAD": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Token.Count : int  3 2 4 1 4 2 2 2 2 1 ...

Comment: The first comment is the input data, the second is output needed for a much bigger file

Comment: if after vectorising the use of `textcnt` it is not fast enough, there are other options you could use. I have added **Update 2** to my answer which uses `strsplit()`, which might be faster. Some simple tests suggests it will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preallocate your storage **before** filling it with the loop. **Never** do what you are doing and concatenate or `r`|`cbind` objects inside a loop. R has to copy, allocate more storage etc at each iteration of the loop and that is overhead that cripples your code.

Create `Token.Count` with enough rows and columns and fill it in the loop. Something like:

```
Token.Count <- matrix(ncol = ?, nrow = nrow(Mydf))
for (i in seq_len(nrow(Mydf))) {
    Token.Count[i, ] <- Myfun(i)
}
Token.Count <- data.frame(Token.Count)
```

Sorry I can't be more specific, but I don't know how many columns `Myfun` returns.

---

**Update 1:** Having taken a look at `textcnt`, I think you can probably avoid the loop altogether. You have something like this data frame

```
DF <- data.frame(CumuCost = c(0.00439, 0.0067), Cost = c(1678, 880),
                 Keyword.text = c("north+face+outlet", "kinect sensor"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

If we strip out the Keywords, and convert it to a list

```
keywrds <- with(DF, as.list(Keyword.text))
head(keywrds)
```

Then we can call `textcnt` *recursively* on this list to count the words in each list component;

```
countKeys <- textcnt(keywrds, split = "[[:space:][:punct:]]+", method = "string",
                     n = 1L, recursive = TRUE)
head(countKeys)
```

the above is almost what you had, except I added `recursive = TRUE` to treat each of the input vectors separately. The final step is to `sapply` the `sum` function to `countKeys` to get the number of words:

```
> sapply(countKeys, sum)
[1] 3 2
```

Which appears to be what you are trying to achieve with the loop and the function. Have I got this right?

---

**Update 2:** OK, if having fixed the preallocation issue *and* used `textcnt` in a vectorized way still isn't quite as quick as you would like, we can investigate other ways of counting words. It could well be possible that you don't need all the functionality of `textcnt` to do what you want. [I can't check if the solution below will work for all your data, but it is a lot quicker.]

One potential solution is to split the `Keyword.text` vector into words using the inbuilt `strsplit` function, for example using `keywrds` generated above and only the first element:

```
> length(unlist(strsplit(keywrds[[1]], split = "[[:space:][:punct:]]+")))
[1] 3
```

To use this idea it is perhaps easier to wrap it in a user function:

```
fooFun <- function(x) {
    length(unlist(strsplit(x, split = "[[:space:][:punct:]]+"),
                  use.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE))
}
```

which we can then apply to the `keywrds` list:

```
> sapply(keywrds, fooFun)
[1] 3 2
```

For this simple example data set we get the same result. What about compute time? First for the solution using `textcnt`, combining two of the steps from **Update 1**:

```
> system.time(replicate(10000, sapply(textcnt(keywrds, 
+                                     split = "[[:space:][:punct:]]+", 
+                                     method = "string", n = 1L, 
+                                     recursive = TRUE), sum)))
   user  system elapsed 
  4.165   0.026   4.285
```

and then for the solution in **Update 2**:

```
> system.time(replicate(10000, sapply(keywrds, fooFun)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.883   0.001   0.889
```

So even for this small sample, there is a considerable overhead involved in calling `textcnt`, but whether this difference holds when applying both approaches to the full data set remains to be seen.

Finally, we should note that the `strsplit` approach can be vectorised to work directly on the vector `Keyword.text` in `DF`:

```
> sapply(strsplit(DF$Keyword.text, split = "[[:space:][:punct:]]+"), length)
[1] 3 2
```

which gives the same results as the other two approaches, and is marginally faster than the non-vectorized use of `strsplit`:

```
> system.time(replicate(10000, sapply(strsplit(DF$Keyword.text, 
+                              split = "[[:space:][:punct:]]+"), length)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.732   0.001   0.734
```

Are any of these faster on you full data set?

**Minor Update:** replicating `DF` to give 130 rows of data and timing the three approaches suggests that the last (vectorized `strsplit()`) scales better:

```
> DF2 <- rbind(DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF,DF)
> dim(DF2)
[1] 130   3
> system.time(replicate(10000, sapply(textcnt(keywrds2, split = "[[:space:][:punct:]]+", method = "string", n = 1L, recursive = TRUE), sum)))
   user  system elapsed 
238.266   1.790 241.404
> system.time(replicate(10000, sapply(keywrds2, fooFun)))
   user  system elapsed 
 28.405   0.007  28.511
> system.time(replicate(10000, sapply(strsplit(DF2$Keyword.text,split = "[[:space:][:punct:]]+"), length)))
   user  system elapsed 
  7.497   0.011   7.528
```